# Building a iOS SDK best practices / best architecture from scratch? Using existing project to import features to wrap into a SDK

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, xcode, sdk

I am currently looking to create an iOS SDK with an existing project. For context, the project is written in Objective C and I'm looking to port some features into an SDK. I'm currently going through tutorials and articles. My questions because I couldn't find online:

- What are best practices for creating an iOS SDK?
- How to smoothly de-couple existing old Objective-C codebase into an SDK (swift)
- How do I architect an SDK? What are best practices for this? I can't find this anywhere.

Comment: a) depends on dependencies of your codebase. Consider supporting simulator and different CPU types for the next 4 years. 
b) most smoothly by renaming if possible so nobody misunderstands what is what.
c) what do you consider is "best practices", static, dynamic, splitted class files, name scheme, examples, selfexplanatory code, doxy compatible commenting, avoiding third party dependencies ? There are books full of different view points out there..

Comment: This WWDC session (https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2019/416/) might be helpful - it will give you insight into some things that might go side ways when you maintain your SDK. With that, you'll know what you should think about when you create initial APIs.